# How to print unknown for not available values in sql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: Users and cities.

Users has user_id and city.
Cities has city and country_name.

I am trying to print the user_id and the corresponding country and if the city is not present in the cities table, I want an unknown to be there in that case.

My Query:

```
Select users.id, cities.country as country
from cities join users on 
cities.city=users.city
```

How do I include the unknown part?

Comment: Drive from users and LEFT JOIN to cities. Review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html for difference between join and left join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT users.id, IFNULL(cities.country, 'unknown') as country
FROM cities 
RIGHT JOIN users ON cities.city = users.city
```

Comment: Right join I think 'trying to print the user_id and the corresponding country and if the city is not present in the cities table' What you had is city not present in users.

Comment: @P.Salmon yep, you are right